# Increased node count in iOS9

Tags: sprite-kit, ios9

Could someone explain why my scene has over 3x more nodes when launched in iOS 9 simulator vs. iOS 8.4 ?

[image: Node Count]

Comment: Are you comparing the numbers from two simulators with different iOS versions, or the iOS 8.4 is running on a real device and iOS 9 is a simulator?

Comment: @Boby_Wan Both are simulators. The only difference between the two scenes is the chosen iOS version. And it's not just the simulator, the same goes with real device with different iOS version.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is the most obvious one, it's the way nodes are counted. iOS9 also counts all the child nodes within each node where earlier versions didn't.